# Kivy ScrollView with over lapping layouts

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I am trying to draw 10 images on the screen, then draw 10 more images (of the same size and shape) over them, in the same locations. This is fine but I also want it all the be scrollable but I get the error **Exception: ScrollView accept only one widget**
This is my code:

```
root = ScrollView(size_hint=(1,1), scroll_wheel_distance=40)

layout1 = GridLayout(cols=2, spacing=0, size_hint=(1, None), row_force_default=True, row_default_height=270)
layout1.bind(minimum_height=layout1.setter('height'))
for i in range(10):
    img = Image(source=UI_bottom_path, size_hint_y=1, allow_stretch=True)
    layout1.add_widget(img)

layout2 = GridLayout(cols=2, spacing=0, size_hint=(1, None), row_force_default=True, row_default_height=270)
for i in range(10):
    img = Image(source=UI_top_path, size_hint_y=1, allow_stretch=True)
    layout2.add_widget(img)

root.add_widget(layout1)
root.add_widget(layout2)
self.add_widget(root)
```

If I comment out "root.add_widget(layout2)" it works fine but doesn't draw the images.
This is how it currently looks:
[image]
This is how each should look:
[image]

Is there a way to get ScrollView and have the layers on top of each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like your error says, ScrollView accepts only one widget. When you commented out "root.add_widget(layout2)" Scrollview has only one widget and that is why it works.
So you can add only one layout to Scrollview like BoxLayout or GridLayout and add the images to the same layout.

And please add your complete code and then we can show an example.